# HotChocolate and UseExceptionHandler middleware

Tags: .net-6.0, hotchocolate

I have a .Net 6 web application which exposes a GraphQL Api for which I am using HotChocolate v13.
I know HotChocolate handles exceptions during query execution and we have implemented an ErrorFilter to transform those errors.

However, my .Net 6 application initially had a UseExceptionHandler middleware registered. Is this middleware still needed? And in what cases, shall it be used ?